# Yii2 выполняет много однотипных запросов. Как от них избавиться?

Tags: php, postgresql, yii2

Пишу сайт на yii2-advansed + postgresql 9.4, смотрю запросы, которые выполняются к базе данных. Вижу, что код такого вида:

```
app\models\Recipe::findOne(15);
```

Генерирует три запроса к базе данных:
1:

```
    SELECT
    d.nspname AS table_schema,
    c.relname AS table_name,
    a.attname AS column_name,
    t.typname AS data_type,
    a.attlen AS character_maximum_length,
    pg_catalog.col_description(c.oid, a.attnum) AS column_comment,
    a.atttypmod AS modifier,
    a.attnotnull = false AS is_nullable,
    CAST(pg_get_expr(ad.adbin, ad.adrelid) AS varchar) AS column_default,
    coalesce(pg_get_expr(ad.adbin, ad.adrelid) ~ 'nextval',false) AS is_autoinc,
    array_to_string((select array_agg(enumlabel) from pg_enum where enumtypid=a.atttypid)::varchar[],',') as enum_values,
    CASE atttypid
         WHEN 21 /*int2*/ THEN 16
         WHEN 23 /*int4*/ THEN 32
         WHEN 20 /*int8*/ THEN 64
         WHEN 1700 /*numeric*/ THEN
              CASE WHEN atttypmod = -1
               THEN null
               ELSE ((atttypmod - 4) >> 16) & 65535
               END
         WHEN 700 /*float4*/ THEN 24 /*FLT_MANT_DIG*/
         WHEN 701 /*float8*/ THEN 53 /*DBL_MANT_DIG*/
         ELSE null
      END   AS numeric_precision,
      CASE
        WHEN atttypid IN (21, 23, 20) THEN 0
        WHEN atttypid IN (1700) THEN
        CASE
            WHEN atttypmod = -1 THEN null
            ELSE (atttypmod - 4) & 65535
        END
           ELSE null
      END AS numeric_scale,
    CAST(
             information_schema._pg_char_max_length(information_schema._pg_truetypid(a, t), information_schema._pg_truetypmod(a, t))
             AS numeric
    ) AS size,
    a.attnum = any (ct.conkey) as is_pkey
FROM
    pg_class c
    LEFT JOIN pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = c.oid
    LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef ad ON a.attrelid = ad.adrelid AND a.attnum = ad.adnum
    LEFT JOIN pg_type t ON a.atttypid = t.oid
    LEFT JOIN pg_namespace d ON d.oid = c.relnamespace
    LEFT join pg_constraint ct on ct.conrelid=c.oid and ct.contype='p'
WHERE
    a.attnum > 0 and t.typname != ''
    and c.relname = 'cook_recipes'
    and d.nspname = 'public'
ORDER BY
    a.attnum;
```

2:

```
SELECT * FROM "cook_recipes" WHERE "id"=15
```

3:

```
select
    ct.conname as constraint_name,
    a.attname as column_name,
    fc.relname as foreign_table_name,
    fns.nspname as foreign_table_schema,
    fa.attname as foreign_column_name
from
    (SELECT ct.conname, ct.conrelid, ct.confrelid, ct.conkey, ct.contype, ct.confkey, generate_subscripts(ct.conkey, 1) AS s
       FROM pg_constraint ct
    ) AS ct
    inner join pg_class c on c.oid=ct.conrelid
    inner join pg_namespace ns on c.relnamespace=ns.oid
    inner join pg_attribute a on a.attrelid=ct.conrelid and a.attnum = ct.conkey[ct.s]
    left join pg_class fc on fc.oid=ct.confrelid
    left join pg_namespace fns on fc.relnamespace=fns.oid
    left join pg_attribute fa on fa.attrelid=ct.confrelid and fa.attnum = ct.confkey[ct.s]
where
    ct.contype='f'
    and c.relname='cook_recipes'
    and ns.nspname='public'
order by
    fns.nspname, fc.relname, a.attnum
```

Что делает второй запрос, понятно. Я ради него этот код и пишу. А что делают два другие и зачем они нужны? И почему они генерируется фрэймворком без моего участия? Могу ли я как-то повлиять на их существование?

Был бы рад, если бы кто-то разъяснил это.

Comment: А субд какую используешь?

Comment: Предположу, что всё это идет от `yii Debuger` - который снизу торчит, если его отключить - скорее всего будет поадекватнее

Comment: @Naumov, postgresql.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, да, я тоже подумал, что это дебагер может быть, но зачем он постоянно один и тот же запрос шлет?

Comment: Да скорее всего дебагер, видимо проверяет есть ли колонка значение и т.д. в таблице

Comment: @Naumov, давайте продолжать логическую цепочку. Зачем Yii-шный дебагер определяет есть ли та или иная колонка в таблице, если не собирается генерировать никакие связи?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Столкнулся с аналогичной проблемой, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, PostgreSQL 9.3.12.

Приведёнными выше запросами фреймворк разбирает структуру таблиц и использует эти данные в дальнейшем при выполнении различных SQL-запросов. Например, "зная" структуру таблицы, фреймворк при выборке данных приводит значения столбцов к нужному типу.

Естественно, каждый раз выполнять подобные запросы накладно, особенно в режиме production. Поэтому фреймворк [кеширует структуру таблицы](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.7/framework/db/Schema.php#L134), если свойство [enableSchemaCache](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-connection.html#$enableSchemaCache-detail) соединения с базой данных установлено в `true`, и при последующих вызовах метода [getTableSchema](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-schema.html#getTableSchema()-detail) берёт структуру из кеша.

По умолчанию в качестве кеширующего компонента используется [FileCache](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-caching-filecache.html). Если по каким-то причинам не удалось закешировать значение, метод [setValue](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.7/framework/caching/FileCache.php#L134) не выдаёт никаких ошибок, поскольку в своих внутренных вызовах использует [оператор управления ошибками](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.errorcontrol.php). Однако, в этом случае отправляется лог-сообщение типа `warning`, которое можно найти в файле `runtime/logs/app.log`, если компонент логгирования сообщений настроен соответствующим образом:

```
'log' => [
    'targets' => [[
        'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
        'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
        'logFile' => '@runtime/logs/app.log'
    ]]
]
```

Если при выполнении очередного SQL-запроса фреймворк каждый раз выполняет дополнительные запросы для определения структуры таблиц, то, скорее всего, в лог-файле будут сообщения вида:

> 2016-04-20 09:51:02 [-][-][-][warning][yii\caching\FileCache::setValue] Unable to write cache file '/home/ezze/Development/qa/runtime/cache/f1/f17bd101a9e7990ecf4753a7d8fb08da.bin': file_put_contents(/home/ezze/Development/qa/runtime/cache/f1/f17bd101a9e7990ecf4753a7d8fb08da.bin): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Другими словами, у процесса недостаточно прав для записи файла кеша (для Ubuntu — у пользователя `www-data`, если SQL-запросы выполняются в контроллере веб-приложения, или у текущего пользователя, если SQL-запросы выполняются в [консольном приложении](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-console.html)).

Для решения проблемы необходимо дать права на запись в директорию `runtime/cache`:

```
chmod 0777 -R runtime
```

#### Замечание!

Файлы логов также могут не писаться из-за недостаточности у пользователей прав на запись в директорию `runtime/logs`.

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужна включить кеширование схем таблиц.
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/db/Connection.php#L194

```
return [
    'components' => [
        'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            //...
            'enableSchemaCache' => true,
//            'schemaCacheDuration' => 3600,

        ],
    ]
];
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Попробую - отпишусь.

Comment: Это ничего не изменило.

Answer (score 4):

Если посмотреть в исходный код, то можно увидеть что:

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-framework/blob/master/db/pgsql/Schema.php

```
@334 строка, метод `findColumns()`
```

Первый твой запрос получает список колонок. Это фишка фреймворка, т.к. для работы в большинстве мест, он работает через колонки (на самом деле это удобно, т.к. можно автоматизировать процесс вывода информации)

```
@219 строка, метод `findConstraints()`
```

Получает список ограничений для колонок.

**Использующих их метод:**

```
@157 строка, метод `loadTableSchema()`
```

Используется для загрузки данных именно о таблице, с которой идет работа.

Все эти запросы выполняются движком, и на самом деле значительно упрощают работу в некоторых случаях.

Comment: Почему такие запросы не нужны для других бд, не postgress? Могу ли я как-то не использовать эти запросы, если считаю, что они мне не нужны. А они мне не нужны, ведь я выбираю только пару значений из таблицы, зачем мне вся информация о всех колонках в таблице, и, тем более, список ограничений, если я только выбираю данные - и все. Я не собираюсь их менять.

Comment: Я видел, что там есть такие запросы, только неясно, зачем они используются для обычного select-а? Другое дело, если нужно автоматически сгенерировать модель - тогда да. Но обычный селект тут при чем?

Comment: И хоть ответ не полный, но лучшего нет )

Comment: @Razzwan извини, очень был занят. Я на самом деле не спрашивал сам себя, поэтому не задавался вопросом почему он вызывает так, и как это отключить. Если поискать по коду, по иерархии в верх то можно найти крайний метод, где он используется. Проще в IDE какую нибудь выкинуть и найти кто и где и как использует эти методы.

Comment: Дело в том, что я это пытался проделать, но мне не удалось отловить момент использования этого кода. Уж очень он глубоко по иерархии - терпения не хватило. Кроме того, наблюдается некая зависимость степени вложенности этого запроса от использования дебагера. Если он выключен, то запрос этот идет первым, если включен, то он идет после основных запросов. Причем пошагово дойти к нему не получается, но если выполнить код до конца, то он появляется. Это странно. Из этой странности и возник вопрос.

Comment: @Razzwan если будет время после работы, дома посмотрю по иерархии. Если что можно создать метод, который будет отсылать запрос к бд, якобы копия их запроса, но без вызова метода получения схемы

Answer (score 3):

Вам дополнительно нужно сконфигурировать компонент, который будет хранить кеш:

```
return [
    'components' => [
        'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'enableSchemaCache' => true,
            'schemaCacheDuration' => 3600,
        ],
     ],
     //
     'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\MemCache',
        // или 'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
     ],
];
```